# Downmix drops low frequency channel

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, stereo, 5.1

I have noticed a problem with FFmpeg downmixing. If I run a command such as

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flac -ac 2 outfile.flac
```

It will have identical result as

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flac \
  -map_channel 0.0.0 \
  -map_channel 0.0.1 \
  -map_channel 0.0.2 \
  -map_channel 0.0.4 \
  -map_channel 0.0.5 \
  outfile.flac
```

That is to say, the fourth channel AKA `0.0.3` AKA `LFE` AKA `low frequency` is
gone. How can I downmix 6 to 2 without losing a channel?

Comment: Another user [referenced your question in #ffmpeg-devel](http://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel-irc/2014-March/001958.html) (search for LFE), and apparently LFE is intended to be excluded when downmixing to stereo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-ac 2` algorithm leaves out "LFE" as can be seen by the 4th column of this
output

```
$ ffmpeg -i infile.flac -ac 2 -v debug -f null -
0.414214 0.000000 0.292893 0.000000 0.292893 0.000000
0.000000 0.414214 0.292893 0.000000 0.000000 0.292893
```

To fix, set the LFE mix level

```
$ ffmpeg -i infile.flac -ac 2 -lfe_mix_level 1 -v debug -f null -
0.320377 0.000000 0.226541 0.226541 0.226541 0.000000
0.000000 0.320377 0.226541 0.226541 0.000000 0.226541
```

- [§ 8 Channel Layout](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Channel-Layout)
- [§ 17 Downmix Levels](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Downmix-Levels)
- [§ 28 Resampler Options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Resampler-Options)
- [§ 34 pan](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#pan)

It should be noted that LFE typcially contains duplicate audio information

> The Low-Frequency Effects (LFE) channel contains extra bass information
> necessary to make effects sound big enough. It should never contain elements
> that are not in other channels

and that including it in a downmix could cause problems

> There are other concerns when adding an LFE signal to the mix. If the LFE is
> simply redistributed within the other channels of the mix, they will usually
> be subject to some low-frequency bandpass filtering. This filtering causes
> phase shifts of the LFE signal. When they are acoustically added within a
> room, these phase shifts are fairly subtle and often go unnoticed. However,
> when they are electronically added together with the five main channels in the
> encoder, they may produce less than desirable results at certain frequencies.
> For this reason, it is recommended that the LFE signal not be used in a Dolby
> Pro Logic II downmix

[Mixing Information for Dolby Pro Logic II](http://web.archive.org/web/dolby.com/assets/pdf/tech_library/214_Mixing%20with%20Dolby%20Pro%20Logic%20II%20Technology.pdf)