# Converting 5.1 audio to stereo and keeping both tracks

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

Let's say I have a video file that has 5.1 audio (maybe AAC or something) and I want to convert that track to stereo so I can use it with Plex without doing any transcoding. Well, I also want to keep the 5.1 track as the 2nd track so if I ever get a 5.1 system, I can use that track. So basically, I just want to copy the video, copy the audio, and add the converted track as the 1st track (the default track).

I've searched all over the web and couldn't find anything about this. I usually just use Handbrake for my video conversions, but it doesn't have a way to just copy the video. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to pull this off by using the following command. I'm not experienced with FFmpeg though, so I'm probably doing something wrong. Any suggestions at all? I don't even think the "96k" part is working.

**Updated working command:**

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" \
-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 \
-c:v copy \
-c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 192k -ac 2 \
-c:a:1 copy \
"output.conv.mkv"
```

**Edit:** Just thought I should mention, I originally used `libfaac` (with 96k bit rate), but actually meant to use `libfdk_aac` here. I changed it to `aac` in case anyone wants to use this command as is and have good quality. By the way, FFmpeg documentation says `libfdk_aac` > `aac` > `libfaac`.

Comment: It should be `-b:a:0`

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, now it works exactly as I wanted and expected it to. I edited the command accordingly.

Comment: Also, unless it's an old version, you can replace `libfaac` with `aac` which is stable and good quality now.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Yeah I knew about that one, but for some reason I needed libfaac before so I downloaded a version with it built in. It's an older version of FFmpeg though, so I might just use the built in aac.

Answer (score 2):

Use ffmpeg as follows

```
ffmpeg -i input -vn -c:a aac -ac 2 stereo.mp4

ffmpeg -i input -i stereo.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 0:a dualaudio.mp4
```