# Convert 5.1 tracks but leaving the originals in MKV

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, matroska

I'd like to convert all audio tracks in MKVs from 5.1 to stereo, leaving the the converted ones in MKV amongside the new ones.

I'm trying to make this an automated process via BAT file. Currently I have the following command that converts 5.1 to Stereo, but it *replaces* the audio tracks, I'd like instead to *add* them amongside the original ones.

```
for /r %%i in (*.mp4) do (

    @ffmpeg.exe ^
        -hide_banner ^
        -v 32 ^
        -stats ^
        -y ^
        -i "%%i" ^
        -map 0:v ^
        -map 0:a ^
        -map 0:s? ^
        -c:s copy ^
        -c:v copy ^
        -acodec ac3 ^
        -ac 2 ^
        -ar 48000 ^
        -ab 640k ^
        -af %aproc2% ^
        -f matroska "%%~ni [Converted].mkv"

)
```

A very similar request was asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1041858/converting-5-1-audio-to-stereo-and-keeping-both-tracks), but the MKV I have can have multiple audio tracks, and I want to convert (and preserve) all of them.