# Is LFE channel completely lost when downmixing 5.1 to stereo using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stereo, 5.1

so, I've been reading a lot about downmixing 5.1 to stereo, but as documentation provides, it creates L and R channels, so is the LFE channel being included down the mix? Is it completely lost? I've tried using `-ac 2.1`, but there's no option for that. It actually returns `Expected int64 for ac but found 2.1`. Sorry if this sounds like a newb question, but I can't seem to find a dead end answer to this.

Comment: I would expect the LFE channel to be mixed in to both the left and right channels, but either at a -3dB level or -10dB level.  FYI -3dB is half the power, so the sum of two halves equals the original signal.  -10 dB is half as loud.

Comment: @sawdust Nope, according to ATSC guidelines, it's skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a5.1stereo). By default the LFE channel is omitted when using `-ac 2`.

[image]

You can of course [create your own mixes](https://superuser.com/questions/852400/properly-downmix-5-1-to-stereo-using-ffmpeg) if you want to keep the LFE channel.

Comment: Ah, so that's what it meant, it was kind of confusing to me, thanks! But what if I want to keep LFE since I have a 2.1 sound system? I tried typing `-ac 2.1` but it's of no use.

Comment: Then you have to create separate channel mapping. The ac option cannot be used for that. I don't know from the top of my head how that works though, have to get back to you.