# FFmpeg - Downmix 5.1 to stereo | -vol option deprecated

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stereo, 5.1

I was using for years a method for dowmix 5.1 to stereo using FFmpeg.

In particular the one called **Downmixing without discarding the LFE channel (Dave_750's answer)** and detailed in this post:

https://superuser.com/a/1410620/1234484

But since the last versions of FFmpeg, the option `-vol` has become deprecated.

So, in this example:

```
ffmpeg -i "signed16bitPCM.wav" -c pcm_s16le -vol 425 -af "pan=stereo|c0=0.5*c2+0.707*c0+0.707*c4+0.5*c3|c1=0.5*c2+0.707*c1+0.707*c5+0.5*c3" "Audio 4 (Dave750 Downmix).wav"
```

What to change the `-vol 425` option to now?

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback ;)